# What are the correct .Trashes Sharing & Permission settings?

Tags: sharing, permission, trash

I was trying to recover some files I accidentally deleted, so I followed this [wikihow article](http://www.wikihow.com/Recover-Accidentally-Deleted-Files-in-OS-X). It makes you change the privileges for the .Trashes file, but then after says, "You can now reset the Access Privileges in the .Trashes Info window back to what they were".

This would be fine, except I didn't pay attention to what they originally were.

If anyone could take a quick look and see what there's are that would be great.

Comment: Not directly related: what is the benefit of the method described in the linked article compared to just opening the Trash from the Dock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mine is at this:

```
d-wx-wx-wt    2 root  wheel       68 Jan 15 17:05 .Trashes/
```

Or, from the finder, all privileges are set to:

```
Write only (Drop Box)
```